# Fetching data but cannot display on the screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am attempting to write code that retrieves news from a free API and organizes them into categories for display. I have successfully implemented the news fetching functionality, as I can see the news being printed on the console. However, when it comes to displaying them on the emulator screen, I encounter an issue where a blank page is presented. No errors are reported, and the widgets containing the news do not appear on the screen. Interestingly, after numerous attempts, such as restarting the app and clicking on the category multiple times, I occasionally achieve the expected result. However, this outcome is rare.

here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Book App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: CategoryScreen(),
        routes: {
          'news screen': (ctx) => NewsScreen(),
        });
  }
}

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<NewsScreen> createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  List<News> news = [];

  Future<void> fetchNews(String title) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=$title&apiKey=89b5c4927784426688b6df37e75ba989');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<News> products = [];
      //print(extractedData['articles']);
      print(extractedData['articles'].length);
      for (var i = 0; i < extractedData['articles'].length; i++) {
        print("here");
        products.add(News(
          title: extractedData['articles'][i]['title'],
          imageUrl: extractedData['articles'][i]['url'],
          description: extractedData['articles'][i]['description'],
        ));
      }
      news = products;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final String categoryTitle = routeArgs['title']!;

    fetchNews(categoryTitle);

    final categoryBooks = news.where((book) {
      return book.title.contains(categoryTitle);
    }).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: news.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.brown[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      news[0].title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      news[0].description,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Categories'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: categories
            .map((bookData) =>
                CategoryItem(bookData.id, bookData.title, bookData.color))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const categories = [
  Category(id: "1", title: "business", color: Colors.pink),
  Category(id: "2", title: "entertainment", color: Colors.blue),
  Category(id: "3", title: "general", color: Colors.red),
  Category(id: "4", title: "health", color: Colors.green),
  Category(id: "5", title: "science", color: Colors.purple),
  Category(id: "6", title: "sports", color: Colors.orange),
  Category(id: "7", title: "technology", color: Colors.brown),
];

class News {
  late final String title;
  late final String imageUrl;
  late final String description;

  News(
      {required this.title, required this.imageUrl, required this.description});

  News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    imageUrl = json['url'];
    description = json['description'];
  }
}

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  const Category(
      {required this.id, required this.title, this.color = Colors.orange});
}

class CategoryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  CategoryItem(this.id, this.title, this.color);

  @override
  State<CategoryItem> createState() => _CategoryItemState();
}

class _CategoryItemState extends State<CategoryItem> {
  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      'news screen',
      arguments: {
        'id': widget.id,
        'title': widget.title,
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              widget.color.withOpacity(0.7),
              widget.color,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screenshots:

[news (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYXpM.png)]

[category screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/93QRV.png)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the desired list is not visible on the screen is that an error is occurring. Some articles in the 'business' category have a null value for the 'description' attribute (this can be confirmed with a print statement). The 'description' property in the 'News' class currently does not allow null values. Therefore, either change the 'description' property in the 'News' class to accept null by using String? or modify it as in the example code I provided.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Book App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: CategoryScreen(),
        routes: {
          'news screen': (ctx) => NewsScreen(),
        });
  }
}

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<NewsScreen> createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  List<News> news = [];

  Future<void> fetchNews(String title) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=$title&apiKey=89b5c4927784426688b6df37e75ba989');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<News> products = [];
      //print(extractedData['articles']);

      for (var i = 0; i < extractedData['articles'].length; i++) {
        print(extractedData['articles'][i]);
        products.add(News(
          title: extractedData['articles'][i]['title'],
          imageUrl: extractedData['articles'][i]['url'],
          description: extractedData['articles'][i]['description'] ?? "",
        ));
      }
      news = products;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArgs =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    final String categoryTitle = routeArgs['title']!;

    fetchNews(categoryTitle);

    final categoryBooks = news.where((book) {
      return book.title.contains(categoryTitle);
    }).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(categoryTitle),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: news.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.brown[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      news[0].title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      news[0].description,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.brown,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Categories'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: categories
            .map((bookData) =>
                CategoryItem(bookData.id, bookData.title, bookData.color))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const categories = [
  Category(id: "1", title: "business", color: Colors.pink),
  Category(id: "2", title: "entertainment", color: Colors.blue),
  Category(id: "3", title: "general", color: Colors.red),
  Category(id: "4", title: "health", color: Colors.green),
  Category(id: "5", title: "science", color: Colors.purple),
  Category(id: "6", title: "sports", color: Colors.orange),
  Category(id: "7", title: "technology", color: Colors.brown),
];

class News {
  late final String title;
  late final String imageUrl;
  late final String description;

  News(
      {required this.title, required this.imageUrl, required this.description});

  News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    imageUrl = json['url'];
    description = json['description'];
  }
}

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  const Category(
      {required this.id, required this.title, this.color = Colors.orange});
}

class CategoryItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  CategoryItem(this.id, this.title, this.color);

  @override
  State<CategoryItem> createState() => _CategoryItemState();
}

class _CategoryItemState extends State<CategoryItem> {
  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      'news screen',
      arguments: {
        'id': widget.id,
        'title': widget.title,
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              widget.color.withOpacity(0.7),
              widget.color,
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It solved the current problem but there is still a problem. I can fetch data but still, I cannot display the data on the screen. This is because I try to assign a list to another list but since fetchNews method works asynchronously, the news list is not working. When I add setState(() {}); just under the news = products statement, it works so I can display the data on the screen. However, it causes us to call the fetchNews method infinitely. As I observe the console, it constantly prints "here" on the console, What would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: how about using futurebuilder?

Comment: Yes, that works. I think using FutureBuilder is mandatory for this type of work. Thanks!